# Can I use Blazor in a Razor class Library to be consumed in different web projects, like WebApi

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have a question about Blazor and the ways to consume it. I am developing a class library (Razor Class Library, but i am not sure it is the  best choice), potentially a Nuget (who knows), doing some business process, and offering a view binded to an url, to access to the dashboard.

So, I simply created a .cshtml page, with the @page attribute to set the url :

```
@page "/dashboard"

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

I use it to display some content.

The library offers extensions methods to include it in different projects (WebAPI and MVC / Blazor app) :

```
public static WebApplicationBuilder AddMyLibrary(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            ....

            return builder;
        }


        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyLibrary(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            return app;
        }
    }
```

So currently, I am able to do it, library is included in projects, businness process are done, and I display a cshtml page. Cool, but I would like to go further.

I would like to take advantage of Blazor Server components to render the dashboard view (and some other pages to display data). I can't figure out if it is possible and how to do that.

Does anyone here has already done it ? Can you explain me the way to do it please ?

Thanks a lot